# Finding two smallest values in a list

Tags: python, list, function, loops, min

I am trying to return the two smallest values for a numeric list as a tuple.
However the next code keeps returning first two values of a list.

```
def test(): 
  list = [4, 5, 1, 9, -2, 0, 3, -5] 
  min1 = list[0]
  min2 = list[1]

  length = len(list)
  
  for i in range(1, length):
    if list[i] < list[0]:
        if list[0] < list[1]:
            list[i] = list[1]
        else:
            list[i] = list[1] 
    else:
        if list[i] < list[1]:
            list[i] = list[1]
    print(min1, min2)

    return (min1, min2) 

test()
```

Console output:

```
4,5
```

Is there any way to do this by iterating?

Comment: The variables `min1` and `min2` don't update, they are not references to the first and second element of the list, they are references to the values that were at indexes 0 and 1 **when the assignment takes place**. That you later change `list[0]` and `list[1]` doesn't matter.

Comment: Also, don't use the variable name `list`, as it clobbers the builtin name.

Comment: A few other tips: consider changing the second `else` to and `elif` and then putting the condition in that,  removing parentheses with return & removing `length` variable by putting `len(list)` (which should *not* be named as a built-in type). But the variables `min1` and `min2` are not modified at any point in the for loop.

Comment: Why not use the min function instead of building your own

Comment: `m1 = min(lst)
m2 = min(v for v in lst if v != m1)
return m1, m2`

Comment: Any reason why you can't: `sl = sorted(list)
m1, m2 = sl[0], sl[1]`. e.g https://ideone.com/TWnlBi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables `min1` and `min2` don't update, they are not references to the first and second element of the list, they are references to the values that were at indexes 0 and 1 **when the assignment takes place**. That you later change `list[0]` and `list[1]` doesn't matter.

In Python, both list indexes and variables are just *references* to the actual objects. Think of Python objects like balloons, and variables and indices are just labels tied to the a string attached to the balloon. You can attach multiple labels to the balloons, but if you than move the label to a different balloon, the *other* labels tied to the old balloon don't follow along.

Here, `min1` and `min2` were tied to balloons that already had the `0` and `1` index labels tied to them. Later on, when you assign to `list[i]`, you retied a specific index label to another balloon, but the `min1` and `min2` labels didn't change.

As a side note, this part of your code has a rather obvious error:

```
if list[0] < list[1]:
    list[i] = list[1]
else:
    list[i] = list[1]
```

Both branches do the exact same thing, assign `list[1]` to `list[i]`.

You are otherwise doing completely incorrect assignments even if you hoped that changing `list[0]` and `list[1]` inside the loop would make a change to the values of `min1` and `min2`, you are changing `list[i]`, the **other** value in the list, the one that's supposed to be smaller.

So for `i = 2`, `list[i]` is `list[2]` and `list[2] < list[0]` is true (1 < 4), you then test if `list[0] < list[1]` (also true, 4 < 5), so you do `list[i] = list[1]`, setting `list[2] = 5`, leaving `list[0]` set to `4`, `list[1]` set to `5`, and in effect throwing away the `1` value that was present at `list[2]` before.

Rather than compare with `list[0]` or `list[1]`, have your loop update `min1` and `min2`:

```
# min1 is always smaller than min2
min1, min2 = list[:2]
if min2 < min1:
    min1, min2 = min2, min1

for i in range(1, length):
    if list[i] < min1:
        min1 = list[i]
    elif list[i] < min2:  # but equal to or greater than min1!
        min2 = list[i]
```

I also made sure that `min1 < min2` at the start, that makes the loop a lot simpler because if `list[i] < min1` is not true then it can *perhaps* be smaller than `min2` but you don't need to test against `min1` a second time.

Note that we assign the `list[i]` values to `min1` and `min2` here, you want to update *those two variables* with the value you just tested, provided `list[i]` is indeed smaller than what you had before.